# How to check whether the character is utf-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to check whether the character set is in utf-8 encoding,through ruby|ror ?

Comment: Do you mean if you already have the String in memory with the correct encoding, or do you mean before you even begin to read the String into memory (say, from a file on disk)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no definite way to do this, in Ruby nor anywhere else:

```
str = 'foo' # start with a simple string
# => "foo" 
str.encoding
# => #<Encoding:UTF-8> # which is UTF-8 encoded
str.bytes.to_a
# => [102, 111, 111] # as you can see, it consists of three bytes 102, 111 and 111
str.encode!('us-ascii') # now we will recode the string to 8-bit us-ascii encoding
# => "foo" 
str.encoding
# => #<Encoding:US-ASCII> 
str.bytes.to_a
# => [102, 111, 111] # see, same three bytes
str.encode!('windows-1251') # let us try some cyrillic
# => "foo" 
str.encoding
# => #<Encoding:Windows-1251> 
str.bytes.to_a
# => [102, 111, 111] # see, the same three again!
```

Of course, you can employ some statistical analysis on the text, and eliminate encodings which the text is not valid for, but theoretically, this is not solvable problem.

Comment: "There's no definite way to do this, in Ruby nor anywhere else", ah, said like an embittered solder of the Unicode wars. Been there, done that, I feel your pain. :-) I also fell back on statistical analysis of the text, which worked, kinda, most of the time. It's amazing how badly broken HTML, RSS and XML can be when someone is determined to make things work without regard for specs.

Comment: What about [String#valid_encoding?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-valid_encoding-3F)? Example: `"Partly valid\xE4 UTF-8 encoding: äöüß".valid_encoding?`

Comment: `valid_encoding?` checks whether a string contains invalid byte sequences. It does not say if the (otherwise valid) byte sequence originates from certain encoding, and I believe that was the question.

Comment: Ok, I see. I understand the question differently, though. I understand: "How can I check if a given string is in valid UTF-8 encoding?" You can very reliably determine if a given byte-sequence is valid `UTF-8`: After only 16 bytes, the probability of a random byte-sequence being valid `UTF-8` [is only 0.01%](http://nickerson.org.uk/blog/2010/is-a-random-set-of-bytes-a-utf-8-string/). So, the algorithm of `str.valid_encoding?` is pretty reliable in determining in checking wether a given string is `UTF-8` encoded.

Answer (score 20):

## Check UTF-8 Validity

For most multi-byte encodings it is possible to programmatically detect invalid byte-sequences. As Ruby by default treats all strings to be `UTF-8`, you can check if a string is given in valid `UTF-8`:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# -------------------------------------------
str = "Partly valid\xE4 UTF-8 encoding: äöüß"

str.valid_encoding?
   # => false

str.scrub('').valid_encoding?
   # => true
```

## Convert Encoding

Additionally, if a string is not valid `UTF-8` encoding, but you know the actual character-encoding, you can convert the string to `UTF-8` encoding.

**Example**
Sometimes, you end up in a situation, in which you know that the encoding of an input-file is either `UTF-8` or `CP1252` (a.k.a. `Windows-1252`).
Check which encoding it is and convert to UTF-8 (if necessary):

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# ------------------------------------------------------
test = "String in CP1252 encoding: \xE4\xF6\xFC\xDF"
File.open( 'input_file', 'w' ) {|f| f.write(test)}

str  = File.read( 'input_file' )

unless str.valid_encoding?
  str.encode!( 'UTF-8', 'CP1252', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '?' )
end #unless
   # => "String CP1252 encoding: äöüß"
```

=======
**Notes**

- It is programmatically possible to detect most multi-byte encodings like UTF-8 (in Ruby, [see: #valid_encoding?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-valid_encoding-3F)) with pretty high reliability. After only 16 bytes, the probability of a random byte-sequence being valid UTF-8 [is only 0.01%](http://nickerson.org.uk/blog/2010/is-a-random-set-of-bytes-a-utf-8-string/). (Compare this with relying on the [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte_order_mark))
- However, it is NOT easily possible to programmatically detect (in)validity of single-byte-encodings like `CP1252` or `ISO-8859-1`. Thus the above code snippet does not work the other way around, i.e. detecting if a String is valid `CP1252` encoding.
- Even though UTF-8 has become increasingly popular as the default encoding in the web, `CP1252` and other `Latin1` flavors are still very popular in the Western countries, especially in North America. Be aware that there a several single-byte encodings out there that are very similar, but slightly vary from `CP1252` (a.k.a. `Windows-1252`). Examples: `ISO-8859-1`, `ISO-8859-15`

Comment: `"String in CP1252 encoding: \xE4\xF6\xFC\xDF"` I believe the question was _how do you check it's in CP1252 encoding_.

Comment: I thought, the question was if a given string is in (valid) `UTF-8` encoding, or not. You do that by calling `str.valid_encoding?` on a String `str` that is in `UTF-8`-encoding. Does that not get clear from my answer?

Comment: Programmatically, you can not (or at least not easily and of course not reliably) check the invalidity of a string in a one-byte-encoding such as `CP1252`. However, you can pretty reliably (depending on the length of the string) check the invalidity of a string in a multi-byte-encoding such as `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"your string".encoding
 # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Or if you want it progmatically,

```
"your string".encoding.name == "UTF-8"
 # => true
```

Comment: This merely checks an encoding set on a string object, not actual encoding of its content. There is no guarantee that the actual content is encoded using the same encoding.